# How To Refresh the Filter Selections After The User View The list?

Tags: swiftui

This ComleteListFilterView is a filter, when the user selected the filter options, the SampleListwill change reflects the filter changes. How to reset the filter each time after the user view the list based on the filter they selected.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.
For example:
Step 1. Click on Filter view --> clicked on the Completed checkbox, go back to Filter list, display only Completed list.

Step 2. Click on Filter view --> clicked on the Closed checkbox, go back to Filter list, display only Closed list, (currently, the list is showing both the Completed and the Closed list).

Step 3. Click on Filter view --> clicked on the Closed checkbox and clicked on the Completed checkbox, go back to Filter list, display the list should show both the Completed and the Closed list).

Step 4. Click on Filter view --> clicked on the Completed checkbox again, go back to Filter list, display only Completed list. Currently, it display the list as if both the Completed and the Closed options were selected.

```
struct SampleListFilterView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var sampleViewModel: SampleViewModel

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:20) {
        Text("Complete Status")
            .font(.system(size: 16))
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        CheckboxField(
            id: "Completed",
            label: "Completed",
            callback: checkboxSelected
        )
        CheckboxField(
            id: "Closed",
            label: "Closed",
            callback: checkboxSelected
        )
        CheckboxField(
            id: "Pending",
            label: "Pending",
            callback: checkboxSelected
        )
    }.padding(20)
    
}


func checkboxSelected(id: String, isMarked: Bool) {
    self.sampleViewModel.dicSampleParameters[id]? = isMarked.description. //---> This is where the filter values changed and triggered the list changes.
}
```

}

This is the custom build checkbox field
import SwiftUI

```
struct CheckboxField: View {
    let id: String
    let label: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let textSize: Int
    let callback: (String, Bool)->()
    
    init(
        id: String,
        label:String,
        size: CGFloat = 10,
        color: Color = Color.black.opacity(0.68),
        textSize: Int = 14,
        callback: @escaping (String, Bool)->()
        ) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.callback = callback
    }
    
    @State var isMarked:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.isMarked.toggle()
            self.callback(self.id, self.isMarked)
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: self.isMarked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(label)
                    .font(Font.system(size: size))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.87))
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Here is the SampleViewModel

```
class  SampleViewModel: ObservableObject, SampleService {
    @Published var dicClaimParameters: Dictionary<String, String> =
                ["Closed": "false", "Completed": "false", "Pending": "false"]{
        didSet{
     
            loadSampleList() // Makes the API Call to load the sample list
        }
    }


func loadSampleList() {
// Makes the API Call to load the sample list

}
```

Comment: Would you prepare standalone minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Asperi, how can I get the sample project to you?